# best way to merge stock prices from pandas in one table?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I started using Python recently and have been using pandas datareader. I have a very simple question.

What would be the best way to create a table with prices of the stocks? The only way I can pull them out is individually but I am having a hard time combining them into one table.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start_D='2015-05-01'
end_D='2015-10-01'
stock = web.DataReader('FB','yahoo',start_D,end_D)
stock2 = web.DataReader('FDX','yahoo',start_D,end_D)
```

---

How would I create one table that includes 'Close' price of these two?

Comment: I provided a way to get all data at once.  If you have a specific way that you'd like to see the data combined, it's best to edit your question and provide what you expect to see and what you've tried.  You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a list into `DataReader` which will return a `pd.Panel` object

```
pnl = web.DataReader(['FDX', 'FB'],'yahoo',start_D,end_D)
```

You can then quickly see it using the `to_frame` method.

```
pnl.to_frame().head(10)
```

[image]

You can get just the `Close` prices

```
pnl.xs('Close', axis='items').head()
```

[image]